# Reflux connect/trigger behavior change after upgrade

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

I recently upgraded Reflux from v0.3.0 to v0.4.1

When I first tested my code after the update, the only change I had to make was to add a key to my component's `Reflux.connect` call.

However, I am experiencing some strange behavior:

```
var SomeActions = Reflux.createActions([
  'updateName'
]);

var SomeStore = Reflux.createStore({
  listenables: [SomeActions],
  init () {
    this.name = '';
    this.time = new Date();
  },
  getInitialState () {
    return {
      time: this.time
    }
  },
  onUpdateName (newName) {
    this.name = newName;
    this.trigger({
      name: this.name
    });
  }
});

var SomeComponent = React.createClass({
  mixins: [React.connect(SomeStore, 'someState')],
  componentDidMount () {
    SomeActions.updateName(this.props.name);
  },
  render () {
    console.log(this.state.someState);
    ...
  }
});
```

When the component first mounts the state is correct, containing just the `time`. However, upon the action being triggered, the state in now incorrect, containing just `name`. The behavior before upgrade was for `trigger` to simply add/update new keys into the state. Thus after the action triggers, I would have expected the state to contain both `time` and `name`.

Did I miss something during the update?

Comment: did you try  `this.trigger({
      name: this.name, time: this.time
    });` ? most likely your state is being replaced with what is triggered which is clearing out the time.

Comment: Yes, that works, but in a complicated app with multiple and complex stores, I don't want each action to force a trigger for every possible state key. I can overcome that by creating a single wrapper function around a trigger that the rest of the store can use, but that still requires that trigger to force every possible state key. I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: ok so where is the setState happening?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I haven't used reflux before so I had to read their documentation. You are using the incorrect method for this.

```
var SomeComponent = React.createClass({
  mixins: [React.connect(SomeStore, 'someState')],
  ----------------^----------------
  componentDidMount () {
    SomeActions.updateName(this.props.name);
  },
  render () {
    console.log(this.state.someState);
    ...
  }
});
```

from the docs

> If all you want to do is update the state of your component to whatever the data store transmits, you can use Reflux.connect(listener,stateKey)

so the data from the store is changing your whole components state.

you can specify what to update like this example from their docs.

```
var Status = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Reflux.listenTo(statusStore,"onStatusChange")],
    onStatusChange: function(status) {
        this.setState({
            currentStatus: status
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        // render using `this.state.currentStatus`
    }
});
```

Or you can return the entire state of the store to the component in your trigger

[DOCS](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs#using-refluxlistento)